# Real interest rate number in Word data bank is yearly or montly?

Tags: online-data-source

I am looking real interest rate from http://databank.worldbank.org. It shows me real interest rate for USA in 2010 was 3%. Does this mean money would increase 3% a month, or 3% a year?

Comment: Important to note, there are times the data will be offered for a month, but annualized, as in "the October inflation rate was an annualized 3%" which simply means if inflation were the same as October for a full 12 months, it would be 3% inflation over that year.

Answer (score 3):

3% in a year. 3% a month would be an enormously high interest rate.